# Laravel query with case and different table subtraction

Tags: php, laravel

Check my laravel query it's not working... but mysql query works fine.

```
$data1 = DB::table(DB::raw('(select sum(case when type="debit" then amount else -amount end) from report) - (select sum(amount) from total) as balance' ))
```

For mysql query please refer sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d0343/9

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I need it in mysql

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Did you want this by company?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the type can't be null and has either credit/debit value, you can use aggregation with `CASE`:

```
select 
    sum(case when type='credit' then amount else -amount end)
from report;
```

#### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd8b8c/22)

In case the column is nullable or other values are allowed in the column `type`, you can modify the above like:

```
select 
    sum(case when type='credit' then amount
             else -amount end)
from report
where type in ('credit', 'debit');
```

#### EDIT:

For the latest edit, calculate the difference from one table and subtract the aggregate from other:

```
select (   
  select sum(case when type='credit' then amount else -amount end)
  from report
  ) - (select sum(amount) from total);
```

Comment: @AZAsoftSolutions do not hesitate to accept his solution if it corresponds to your needs :)

Comment: I want to subtract this amount to another table amount it's possible ?

Comment: In that case, do aggregation separately to find the sums, and then subtract

Comment: @AZAsoftSolutions - Updated. Please check

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(case type when 'credit' then amount when 'debit' then -amount else 0 end)
from report
```

Comment: I want to subtract this amount to another table amount it's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

select (sum(case when type='credit' then amount else -amount end)) - (select sum(amount) from total)
  from report

Comment: I need it in laravel query